# Converter valor decimal para binário em C

Tags: c

Olá, tenho o seguinte exercício:
Faça um programa que leia números positivos e os converta em binário. Cada número binário deverá ser salvo em uma linha de um arquivo texto. O programa termina quando o usuário digitar um número negativo.
Logo abaixo está meu código, ele não escreve os valores convertido em binário no arquivo, se puderem me dar algum feedback de como posso estar corrigindo e melhorando o código por favor.

OBS: Estou reaproveitando essa função de alguns exercícios anteriores, ela funciona bem pra converter os valores e mostra-los na tela, o problema é na hora de passa-los para o arquivo. De qualquer forma se existir algum outro método mais eficiente de fazer essas conversões ficarei grato em poder conhece-las.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void ConvertDecimalsToBinari(int d, FILE *ListOfBinaries){
    if(d == 1){
        fprintf(ListOfBinaries, "%d", d%2);
        return;
    }
    ConvertDecimalsToBinari(d/2, ListOfBinaries);
    fprintf(ListOfBinaries,"%d", d%2);
}


int main(){

FILE *ListOfBinaries;
char FileName[20];
int decimal;

printf("Informe o arquivo (.txt) onde serão salvos os valores: ");
scanf("%s", FileName);

ListOfBinaries = fopen(FileName, "w+");
if(ListOfBinaries == NULL){
    perror("Erro: " );
    exit(1);
}

do{
    printf("Digite um valor inteiro para conversão: ");
    scanf("%d", &decimal);
    ConvertDecimalsToBinari(decimal, ListOfBinaries);
    fprintf(ListOfBinaries, "\n");
}while(decimal >= 0);

fclose(ListOfBinaries);
ListOfBinaries = NULL;

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

essa sua função recurssiva está bugada , e não funciona nada bem , e o nome do arquivo precisa conter o tipo de arquivo , que aí é ".txt" ,
então faça uma concatenação do nome mais o tipo , e do modo como está o código faz a conversão mas coloca os bit's ao contrário da ordem normal ,
e só converte numeros positivos e menor que 256 , equivalente a um byte .

```
#include    <stdio.h>
#include    <conio.h>
#include    <iso646.h>
#include    <stdlib.h>
#include    <string.h>
#include    <windows.h>
#include    <math.h>
#include    <time.h>
#include    <locale.h>
void ConvertDecimalsToBinari(int d, FILE *ListOfBinaries)
{
  int vet[8] = {};
  if(d<0 || d>255)return;    /// perimitido numeros nessa faixa de um Byte
  fprintf(ListOfBinaries,"%5d = ",d);
  int count = 7;             /// comeCa na Ultima posiCAo do vetor      
  do
  {                          /// o Resto da DivisAo eh o bit do binario      
    vet[count] = d%2;        /// armazena os binArios de traz p/ frenTe      
    count--;                 /// isso coloca na Ordem certa                  
    d /= 2;                  /// divide p/ o prox bit                        
  }while(d > 0);             /// condicAo de saida do loop eh d=0            
  for(; d<8; d++)            /// d jah eh =0 e vai ate 7 
    fprintf(ListOfBinaries,"%d",vet[d]); /// Grava os Oito bit's no Arquivo TXT
}
int main    ( int argc, char *argv[]                     )
{
  setlocale(LC_ALL,"");
  FILE *ListOfBinaries;
  char FileName[20] = {"aquilvus"};
  int decimal;
  printf("Informe o arquivo (.txt) onde serão salvos os valores: ");
  scanf("%s", FileName);
                                                       /// concatenar para o nome completo
  ListOfBinaries = fopen(strcat(FileName,".txt"), "a");    /// ".txt" especf o tipo de arq
  if(ListOfBinaries == NULL)                               /// "a" abre p/ Ler e/ou gravar no final do arquivo
  {
      perror("Erro: " );
      exit(1);
  }
  do
  {
    printf("Digite um valor inteiro para conversão: ");
    scanf("%d", &decimal);
    ConvertDecimalsToBinari(decimal, ListOfBinaries);
    fprintf(ListOfBinaries,"%s\n", "");
  }
  while(decimal >= 0);
  fclose(ListOfBinaries);
  ListOfBinaries = NULL;
  system ("start explorer.exe");
  printf("\n\n\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ótimo, muito obrigado. Existem alguns conceitos no seu código dos quais ainda não vi na linguagem, como os parâmetros dentro de 'main()' e algumas bibliotecas, vou fazer o possível para extrair a lógica usada. Obrigado pelos esclarecimentos!